# Get custom data from jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom attribute called itemID - how do I get its value so I can put it in the URL similar to how I get the id?

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.eventImage').click(function(e){ 
    $this = $(this);
       $.ajax({
        url: "http://server.local/action.php?event="+$this.attr("id")+"&itemID="+$this.data('itemID'),
        type:'POST',
        });
    }); 

});
</script>
```

html:

```
<img class='eventImage' id='ITEM_3_ON' src='images/livingroom/1-2.png' data-itemID='3'/>
```

Comment: `e != event` in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.eventImage').click(function(e) {
       $this = $(this); // Make a copy of the image.
       $.ajax({
        url: "http://server.local/action.php?event="+$this.attr("id")+"&itemID="+$this.data('itemID'), // Use $this here.
        type:'POST',
        });
    }); 
});
```

**Changes:**

The `event.target` has a tendency to change, I guess, because you are calling inside the callback function of AJAX.

1. Use `$this` for referencing the current object inside AJAX call.
2. Use the same `$this` to get the `id` too.

Comment: target can't change when there are no children which imge can't have

Comment: @johncs What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: i am using jquery 2.1.4

Comment: ive updated my code with the current version...not much has changed, just the change you gave me.  also, theres no other code yet, just html tags and body tags.  the page is getting called, i know that for sure because i can see events happening.   however the itemID is not making it

Comment: i was able to get it working by using the 'name' attribute instead of a custom data field.  its not the ideal way, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `$this.attr("data-itemID")` is the solution..

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the transfered event then you should use e.target.id and for  attribute e.target.attributes['data-itemID'].value not event.target.id as you transfered e into the click handler function..

Note that e.target returns a javascript object not a jquery object.

Comment: instead of passing the value 3, it's passing this: [object%20Attr]